# Facebook PHP SDK url format

Tags: php, facebook, url, sdk

In the following URL:

```
https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/s130x130/10301445_536464219792199_1470825171431133314_n.jpg?oh=f4ce5bfb1ac7592b5f38876fb2d63682&oe=5442F5AB
```

How would one make the image appear larger?

I've tried changing the `130x130` to higher values but that did not work.

Comment: This is just for a sample.
For real image: https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1/q71/10301445_536464219792199_1470825171431133314_n.jpg?oh=f4ce5bfb1ac7592b5f38876fb2d63682&oe=5442F5AB

For 720x720: https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/t1/q71/s720x720/10301445_536464219792199_1470825171431133314_n.jpg?oh=f4ce5bfb1ac7592b5f38876fb2d63682&oe=5442F5AB

Comment: Why does my pagefeed['picture'] return me the sample image? How do retrieve the original picture of the 720 one?

Comment: For real image: https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/t1/q71/10301445_536464219792199_1470825171431133314_n.jpg?oh=f4ce5bfb1ac7592b5f38876fb2d63682&oe=5442F5AB

Comment: I know that, but how did you generate that link? I use the PHP SDK and when I retrieve my feed, and I generate feed['picture'] it gives me the sample image. How do I get the real image, what parts of the url change?

Comment: Please paste the relevant piece of code. That sole URL's not going to be much use to anyone who might want to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer and I will share it with you for future reference.

When using Facebook's PHP SDK, you can retrieve a profile's or page's feed. This information is retrieved from http://graph.facebook.com/

When I retrieved my page's feed, it returned me all the posts, photo's, ... that were posted on the page. With a photo post, you get 2 variables that are related to the photo itself. $feed['picture'] and $feed['object_id'].

$feed['picture'] is a sample/thumbnail of the photo posted, so smaller sized and not really viable to use on any website or project.
After some reading I found out that you could do a SECOND request to http://graph.facebook.com with the object_id of the photo. That way I could retrieve multiple sizes of the photo (object) in question.

There are a lot of solutions out there, replacing _n with _o, or replacing the size numebrs (for example 130x130) to larger numbers (for example 720x720), but this no longer worked as far as I have tried.

I hope this makes sense!